# What's the most bullet-proof way to upload large files in a web app?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, upload

We have to accept large file uploads (video content) and want to do that in a way that works well across all standards-compliant browsers and plug-ins. Our current setup looks like this:

- [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org)
- input type="file" for graceful degradation

On the server-side, we have [nginx](http://nginx.net/) and the [upload module](http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html) streaming the uploaded files into the server, then handing the requests off to a merb app.

Unfortunately, it looks like the recently released Adobe Flash Player 10 broke every single free/open uploading flash component out there (and then, some other sites which have their own proprietary versions as well), but some other sites, such as [Flickr](http://flickr.com) and [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com), seem to work just fine.

I've been poking around looking for other ways of doing this, but since compatibility with both Flash 9 and 10 is mandatory, I couldn't find a suitable solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File uploading is always a pain.

I tried a few flash uploaders a while ago and it seems all of them had the limitation of not being to display a progress bar on Macs. Not to mention the upgrade to flash 10 broke most flash uploaders so users of our company app went from multiselecting a whole folder with 50 files to upload at once to uploading 50 files one at a time.

Java uploaders work fine (even through Java updates) but if you don't have small user base that you can explain why they need to download java and allow an applet to run in their browser, most will not use it.

I think the middle ground is to just use ftp. It's old but effective, works with extremely large files and multiple files.

Comment: My vote is just Java, virtually everybody has it now.  FTP isn't going to work on your average user.

Comment: +1 for TravisO, everyone has Java whether they know it or not.

Answer (score 2):

Java uploaders are the best tools for large files, try [Rad Upload](http://www.radinks.com/upload/) it's very useful for large files.

Answer (score 2):

Try [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/). It's a MooTools uploader and it works for both Flash 9 and 10.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [JumpLoader](http://www.jumploader.com/) with good results. Support is great, free version available, even includes some basic image processing functions (crop, resize, etc).

According to my google analytics data (non-tech website), 99% of visitors have Java installed, so that's not a problem.

Of course, always provide a simple `input type="file"` alternative, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

New versions (v2.2.0+) of SWFUpload deal with the Flash 10 issue.

Comment: They seem to in some cases - unfortunately, they don't seem to call the update_progress_handler events on some of the platforms we tested (MacOS X 10.5.5 - Safari 3.x and Firefox 3).

Do you think that would be an unrelated issue?